# Creating a "table" within p:picklist using itemLabel

Tags: jsf, xhtml, primefaces

I was wondering if it is possible to create more complex itemLabel for the primefaces picklist. Basically I am using the picklist as a way for users to move a contact (think Outlook contact) from one list to another list. The code I have for itemLabel looks like this:

```
itemLabel="#{contact.firstName} #{contact.lastName} &#160; &#160; &#160; #{contact.email}"
```

This leads to each 'item' looking sloppy and makes it difficult to space properly. I would prefer to have 2 (or more) "columns" within the itemLabel, so it can be spaced appropriately. If this is not possible, is there another component that I could use that would be more appropriate for this type of user interaction? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `p:column` tag inside pick list to define more columns, and better organize list presentation to user. Structure would be something like this:

```
<p:pickList>
  <p:column></p:column>
  <p:column></p:column>
</p:pickList>
```

You can check [second example on Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/picklist.jsf)

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure how I didn't see that before. This was exactly what I was looking for.